# Parse GPS track data into 10 sec intervals

Tags: gps, gpx, geolocation, gpsbabel, movement-data

I have a GPX track containing latitude, longitude and elevation data. The recordings are done by a Garmin device and have been recorded in varying intervals (between 1 and 44 seconds). I would like to know my (interpolated) location data for every 10 seconds.

I have installed gpsbabel and ran this per page 138 in the [manual](https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.5.0/gpsbabel-1.5.0.pdf) (on Mac OSX)

```
gpsbabel -t -i gpx -f in.gpx -x track,pack,split=10s,title="LOG # %c" -o gpx -F out.gpx
```

The file out.gpx is created, but appears to be exactly the same as the input file. Am I using the wrong function?

When the input timestamps are

```
2016-11-27T22:56:58.000Z
2016-11-27T22:57:02.000Z
2016-11-27T22:57:07.000Z
2016-11-27T22:57:13.000Z
2016-11-27T22:57:19.000Z
```

I would like to have a 10 second interval output like

```
2016-11-27T22:56:58.000Z
2016-11-27T22:57:08.000Z
2016-11-27T22:57:18.000Z
```

with the corresponding (calculated) coordinates for those sections.

A sample of my original data can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/LR5V5i24).